# Enable a Enter as Carriage Return on TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a simple textbox in my aspx page, which for some reason I don't understand, the enter key doesn't work.

**EDITED**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Process.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server" class="innermainclass">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbdesc" Text='<%# Eval("Descritivo") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Width="450px" Height="150px" />
</asp:Content>
```

When I pressed "Enter" or "Return" it doesn't do anything. I would like it to make a carriage return.

Thanks.

Comment: It works for me, so there must be something that you haven't shown.

Comment: What is the rendered HTML?

Comment: `<textarea name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txbdesc" rows="5" cols="20" id="txbdesc" style="height:150px;width:450px;">1234567890</textarea>`

Comment: That's valid and does what you expect, is there JavaScript on the page that interacts with it?

Comment: `CodeFile="Process.aspx.cs"` change this line to the following 
`CodeBehind="Process.aspx.cs"`

Comment: OK, just saw all rendered html, and I have a jquery function that prevents the enter key so that several fields, in several tabs, doesn´t permit the enter key.
`$(":input").keypress(function (e) {
                //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    return false;
                }
            });`
That function must exists, how can I bypass this, for some specific fields?

Comment: show us the function..

Comment: @NunoRamos, this function is too general, it disables Enter for all your inputs on the whole page. You should really consider narrowing it down. Say mark necessary inputs that do not allow Enter with some new class, and then apply this function to only inputs with this class

Comment: Also please put this code into the question body, it is very relevant to your question

Comment: @Andrei, thank you for your suggestion, I'm going to try it.

Comment: Just tried it, it works fine.